# Moving html table columns in vim

Tags: vim, html

I have an HTML table with rows like this:

`<tr> <td>DATE</td> <td>NUMBER</td> <td>DESCRIPTION</td> <td>DEADLINE</td> </tr>`

`<tr> <td>6/7</td> <td>1</td> <td>foo1</td> <td>bar1</td> </tr>`

`<tr> <td>6/15</td> <td>2</td> <td>foo2</td> <td>bar2</td> </tr>`

`<tr> <td>6/20</td> <td>3</td> <td>foo3</td> <td>bar3</td> </tr>`

`... etc ...`

What I'd like to do is I'd like to shift all of the entries in the DESCRIPTION column down. So I'd like to move `foo1` one step down, I'd like to move `foo2` one step down, etc. But I would like to preserve everything else in the table. How can I do this in vim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understand is that you want the table to look like that, with a weird empty cell under `DESCRIPTION`:

```
<tr> <td>DATE</td> <td>NUMBER</td> <td>DESCRIPTION</td> <td>DEADLINE</td> </tr>
<tr> <td>6/7</td> <td>1</td> <td></td> <td>bar1</td> </tr>
<tr> <td>6/15</td> <td>2</td> <td>foo1</td> <td>bar2</td> </tr>
<tr> <td>6/20</td> <td>3</td> <td>foo2</td> <td>bar3</td> </tr>
…
```

Am I right? Here is **one** way you can do it:

1. Format this code with `:%!column -t` or a Vim plugin:

   ```
   <tr>  <td>DATE</td>  <td>NUMBER</td>  <td>DESCRIPTION</td>  <td>DEADLINE</td>  </tr>
   <tr>  <td>6/7</td>   <td>1</td>       <td>foo1</td>         <td>bar1</td>      </tr>
   <tr>  <td>6/15</td>  <td>2</td>       <td>foo2</td>         <td>bar2</td>      </tr>
   <tr>  <td>6/20</td>  <td>3</td>       <td>foo3</td>         <td>bar3</td>      </tr>
   ```
2. Move to first item then delete it with `dit`. `foo1` is now in the default register.
3. Start a macro with `qx` (use any available letter instead of `x`).
4. Move to the line below with `j`.
5. Visually select the content of the tag with `vit`.
6. Replace the selected text (`foo2`) with the content of the default register (`foo1`) using `p`.
7. Stop the macro with `q`. The content of the default register is now `foo2`, ready to use for the next time the macro is invoked.
8. Apply the macro as many times you need with something like `<number of rows>@x`.

End result:

```
<tr>  <td>DATE</td>  <td>NUMBER</td>  <td>DESCRIPTION</td>  <td>DEADLINE</td>  </tr>
<tr>  <td>6/7</td>   <td>1</td>       <td></td>         <td>bar1</td>      </tr>
<tr>  <td>6/15</td>  <td>2</td>       <td>foo1</td>         <td>bar2</td>      </tr>
<tr>  <td>6/20</td>  <td>3</td>       <td>foo2</td>         <td>bar3</td>      </tr>
…
```

Condensed version:

```
:%!column -t<CR>
(movement)
ditqxjvitpq
17@x
```

Use another named register at step 2 if you don't want to mess with the default register (and your system clipboard if applicable).

If you only want to increment the number in `foo2` and Co, The [VisIncr plugin](http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=670) is very good.